# c# button click pass parameter to another class and execute

Tags: c#, class, parameters

Im trying to create shop packet generator. I got main.cs where I got textbox and button. I also got class listen.cs where I got working code responsible for listening for packets from specific IP address.

What I would like to have is something like that:

```
private void btn_SEND_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sourceIP = "1.1.1.1";
        Listen myListen = new Listen(sourceIP);
    }
```

So when user click button, IP address will be passed to listen.cs and whole code from that class will be executed. In the future I would like execute code from two separated classes simultaneously.

Problem is I do not know how to execute this properly. What should be within my listen.cs class to accept that parameter and execute code.

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, it sounds like you would want the *constructor* (important search term for you) to accept an *argument*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a constructor in your `Listen` class (`listen.cs`) that will accept a `string`, like this:

```
public class Listen
{
    private string _sourceIp;

    public Listen(string sourceIp)
    {
        _sourceIp = sourceIp;
    }
}
```

Now you can use the Source IP value in your Listen class via the `_sourceIp` variable.

Note: If you need access outside your class, then you can create a property, like this:

```
public string SourceIp { 
    get { return _sourceIp; } 
    set { _sourceIp = value; } 
}
```

OR use an automatic property like this:

```
public string SourceIp { get; set; }
```

Note: An automatic property will create a `private` backing field by default and will eliminate the need for your `_sourceIp` variable, so your class would look like this:

```
public class Listen
{
    public string SourceIp { get; set; }

    public Listen(string sourceIp)
    {
        SourceIp = sourceIp;
    }
}
```

Note: You are now applying the value passed to your constructor to the property directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your reference about constructor in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx